# Docker service fails on Debian GNU/Linux 11 due to docker-ce

Tags: linux, docker, debian, remote-server, docker-ce

**ERROR**

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code)
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 145292 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 145292 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 148ms
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of **docker version**

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.3
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.7
 Git commit:        3e7cbfd
 Built:             Tue Apr  4 22:03:23 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`
```

Output of **docker info**

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.4
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.17.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Could anyone help me with the issue? I can not seem to find any solution on the internet.
P.S. I'm not using VPN.

Comment: Can you check do you have `containerd` is installed? As docker is showing error while installing docker.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar, the output of the **dpkg -l containerd***: `ii  containerd     1.4.13~ds1-1~deb11u3 amd64        open and reliable container runtime
rc  containerd.io  1.6.20-1             amd64        An open and reliable container runtime`

Comment: All docker packages: `ii  docker-buildx-plugin                 0.10.4-1~debian.11~bullseye    amd64   Docker Buildx cli plugin.
rc  docker-ce  5:23.0.3-1~debian.11~bullseye  amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-cli    5:23.0.3-1~debian.11~bullseye  amd64        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-rootless-extras  5:23.0.3-1~debian.11~bullseye  amd64        Rootless support for Docker.
ii  docker-compose-plugin  2.17.2-1~debian.11~bullseye    amd64        Docker Compose (V2) plugin for the Docker CLI.`

Answer (score 1):

I checked daemon logs with the command

`journalctl -u docker`

and the following error was displayed:

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: 
error obtaining controller instance: 
failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t
```

Then Switching to iptables-legacy helped:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

Attaching the [source](https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269) for reference.